# Python Outlook Emails identification and reading links using IMAP

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, imap, imaplib

I am trying to write a python3 code that logs in an Outlook Email account and then searches for Emails with some specific filters (FROM, SUBJECT, DATE) to fetch it then parse it and then take a specific link out of its body, using IMAP and BeautifulSoup.

I was able to do:
1- logging in my Email account and then my INBOX using IMAP.
2- fetch emails and then parsing them.
3- locating a link on a different .txt file

What I wasn't able to do is:
searching for specific Emails using IMAP.

I was wondering if anyone can help me by showing the right syntaxes to search for certain Emails on Outlook.

Thank you in advance.

```
import imaplib
import email
from email.utils import parseaddr

username = 'hae42@mail.aub.edu'
password = 'Null'
Mymail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com')#imap- 
mail.outlook.com or outlook.office365.com
Mymail.login(username, password)
#Mymail.list() #OUT: list of "folders"
Mymail.select("INBOX") #connect to inbox

def get_body(msg):
    if msg.is_multipart():
        return get_body(msg.get_payload(0))
    else:
        return msg.get_payload(None,True)

def search(key, value, Mymail):
    result, data = Mymail.search(None, key, '"()"'.format(value))
    return data

result, data = Mymail.fetch(latest_email_id, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])

 print(search('FROM', 'email@outlook.example'))
```

Comment: Have you read the search specification of RFC 3501?  imaplib doesn't provide anything fancy, you just provide the raw search string to the library.

Comment: I think it would be better if I provide more explanation, I just added a snippet of the code that reads Outlook Emails.
In a GMAIL example, that same search function is used to specify the Emails you want to fetch then parse, with identifying the sender, "FROM", "EXAMPLE@GMAIL.COM". and that returns [b '1 2 3'] for example as in the first 3 emails in your inbox are from that sender.
My problem is, I am not knowing how to implement this for Outlook emails, it returns b ' ' as in there are no Emails from that sender I specified, although I am sure there is (I checked).

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to read emails from both Outlook and Gmail (and others) using [IMAPClient](https://pypi.org/project/IMAPClient/) and [mailparser](https://pypi.org/project/mail-parser/):

```
from imapclient import IMAPClient
import mailparser

with IMAPClient(self.host) as server:
    server.login(self.username, self.password)
    server.select_folder('INBOX')
    messages = server.search(['UNSEEN', ])  # in your case: ['FROM', 'email@outlook.example']

    # for each unseen email in the inbox
    for uid, message_data in server.fetch(messages, 'RFC822').items():
        email_message = mailparser.parse_from_string(message_data[b'RFC822'])
```

You can then access the elements of the email as described in the mail-parser doc (link above).  For example:

```
# parse html from email
soup = BeautifulSoup(email_message.body, "html.parser")
msg_body = soup.get_text()
```